# Universal App: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)

Tags: c#

I have problem with creating xaml control. I write new project in VS 2015 in universal app.
this is my code:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TechnologyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Level}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

in line 
I get error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)

Can anyone help me ?